# Using array to create reports copy from a data source using a unique list to create individual reports

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below code which I found on this site some time ago. The code is running as it should as per input.

The ws1 is a unique list of cost centres ws2 is long long data sheet of cost against cost centres.

What I want this code to do is, find all the cost's associated with the first code on ws1 from ws2 paste them into a third sheet (template), then I have code that turns that sheet into a report for that cost centre, then clears its contents.

I then want the code to continue and find them all for the next code on ws2, paste into third sheet so I can create a report and so on etc etc.

there are 65000 records on ws2 all associated with one of the 26 ish cost centres ws1.

```
 Option Explicit     

 Sub createReports()

   Dim ws1 As Variant, ws2 As Variant, ws3 As Variant
   Dim i As Long, j As Long

    ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UniqueList").UsedRange
    ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data Sheet").UsedRange

 ReDim ws3(11, 0)
      For i = 1 To UBound(ws1)
            For j = 1 To UBound(ws2)
                If Trim$(ws1(i, 1)) = Trim$(ws2(j, 1)) Then
                   ReDim Preserve ws3(11, Count)
                      ws3(0, Count) = ws2(j, 1)
                      ws3(1, Count) = ws2(j, 2)
                      ws3(2, Count) = ws2(j, 3)
                      ws3(3, Count) = ws2(j, 4)
                      ws3(4, Count) = ws2(j, 5)
                      ws3(5, Count) = ws2(j, 6)
                      ws3(6, Count) = ws2(j, 7)
                      ws3(7, Count) = ws2(j, 8)
                      ws3(8, Count) = ws2(j, 9)
                      ws3(9, Count) = ws2(j, 10)
                      ws3(10, Count) = ws2(j, 11)
                     Count = Count + 1

               End If

         Next j

        Call PasteArray(transposeArray(ws3), ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template").[A2])
        Call createWrkBooks
        Call clearContents

   Next i



 Set ws1 = Nothing
 Set ws2 = Nothing

 End Sub
```

currently the code runs but copies all the data from ws2 but groups the rows together in the order of the cost centres.

What I would like it to do is create 26 individual reports all copied first into the template which my other codes will save as a workbook then clear the contents. ready to be repopulated.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Why didn't work what you tried? Any errors? Where exactly did you get stuck? There is no question in your "question". This looks like a *"Here is my code, please fix it."* question.

Comment: the question is the code works as it is written. but I want it to stop after finding all the entries for the first code in ws1 then continue after I have saved and cleared the template. Basically before looking at the next I, at the moment it creates 26 reports but with ALL the date in from ws2

Comment: You probably need to put your logic to "save" and "clear" the template right after `Count = Count + 1` and before `End If`

Comment: hi I will try wont that mean that it is not progressing to the next row on ws2 ie looking at the Next J

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the input data and the actual output as it is now? That would make it much easier.

Comment: input and output are the same basically I want to looking up row 1 in ws1 and all rows that match in ws2 copy to the template. but Before moving onto row 2 in ws1 I want to save the template and clear it

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier (and faster) to loop throug the codes in ws1 and filter ws2 for each of the codes to copy the filtered result to the template? I think that's easier than a doubled loop throug all the data.

Comment: possibly but would need to be pulled into an array in RAM, it takes too long to run otherwise.

Comment: A doubled loop takes longer than a filter I guess. You can still read the filter result into an array if need that.

Comment: the double loop is happening in RAM in this array that why this code takes less than 2 seconds to run and less than 30 seconds to save 26 reports

Comment: I have used this code before on larger data sets but I had multiple conditions what that enabled it to only pull out mismatching data. this time I want it to pull out only data that matches.

Comment: ehhhm I think I got it. You forgot to reset to `Count = 0` after you cleared the template. You also need to clear the the array `ws3` (eg `ReDim` without `Preserve`) but instead you append it with the next code of ws1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work. You just need to re-initialize your `Count` and `ws3` for each `i`. Otherwise you are appending your new data to the old one.

```
're-initialize for the next i
ReDim ws3(11, 0) 'needs to be inside the For i loop
Count = 0
```

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub createReports()
    Dim ws1 As Variant, ws2 As Variant, ws3 As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UniqueList").UsedRange
    ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data Sheet").UsedRange

    For i = 1 To UBound(ws1)
        're-initialize for the next i
        ReDim ws3(11, 0) 'needs to be inside the For i loop
        Count = 0

        'collect everything for the current i
        For j = 1 To UBound(ws2)
            If Trim$(ws1(i, 1)) = Trim$(ws2(j, 1)) Then
                ReDim Preserve ws3(11, Count)
                ws3(0, Count) = ws2(j, 1)
                ws3(1, Count) = ws2(j, 2)
                ws3(2, Count) = ws2(j, 3)
                ws3(3, Count) = ws2(j, 4)
                ws3(4, Count) = ws2(j, 5)
                ws3(5, Count) = ws2(j, 6)
                ws3(6, Count) = ws2(j, 7)
                ws3(7, Count) = ws2(j, 8)
                ws3(8, Count) = ws2(j, 9)
                ws3(9, Count) = ws2(j, 10)
                ws3(10, Count) = ws2(j, 11)
                Count = Count + 1
            End If
        Next j

        'save the current i colleted data
        Call PasteArray(transposeArray(ws3), ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template").[A2])
        Call createWrkBooks
        Call ClearContents
    Next i

    Set ws1 = Nothing
    Set ws2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: you sir are a genius please change your name to Einstein

Answer (score 1):

## From Array to Array Transpose

You haven't declared `count`. Use `Option Explicit` to avoid this.

```
Option Explicit
```

### 0-based Version

This version should work right now.

```
Sub createReports0B()

    Const cRows As Long = 10
    
    Dim ws1 As Variant, ws2 As Variant, ws3 As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim count As Long
    
    ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UniqueList").UsedRange
    ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data Sheet").UsedRange
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(ws1)
        count = 0
        ReDim ws3(cRows, count)
        For j = 1 To UBound(ws2)
            If Trim$(ws1(i, 1)) = Trim$(ws2(j, 1)) Then
                ReDim Preserve ws3(cRows, count)
                For k = 0 To cRows
                    ws3(k, count) = ws2(j, k + 1)
                Next k
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next j

        PasteArray transposeArray(ws3), ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template").[A2]
        createWrkBooks
        ClearContents
     
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

### 1-based Version

I would have gone with a 1-based array, because it can be transferred quicker into a range (without looping).

```
Sub createReports1B()

    Const cRows As Long = 11
    
    Dim ws1 As Variant, ws2 As Variant, ws3 As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim count As Long
    
    ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UniqueList").UsedRange
    ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data Sheet").UsedRange
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(ws1)
        count = 1
        ReDim ws3(1 To cRows, 1 To count)
        For j = 1 To UBound(ws2)
            If Trim$(ws1(i, 1)) = Trim$(ws2(j, 1)) Then
                ReDim Preserve ws3(1 To cRows, 1 To count)
                For k = 1 To cRows
                    ws3(k, count) = ws2(j, k)
                Next k
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next j
        
        ' You have to change here because ws3 is a 1B 2D array.
        PasteArray transposeArray(ws3), ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template").[A2]
        createWrkBooks
        ClearContents
    
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: creates a mismatch type13 error on the ReDim Preserve ws3 line, thank you for this however the other code runs well now and very fast. Does anyone know if its possible to stop the new workbook been created from showing on the task bar?

Comment: @Leighholling: I have added the **Erase ws3** line. Sorry. Only the first version will work, for the second you will have to change your **PasteArray** code.

Comment: it still does not like where the redim is